# Conditionally show filtered posts or normal posts with Javascript in Gatsby project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I want to keep my PostList component generic. If `featured` is set for a post I want to render the featured posts, otherwise the posts (without `featured`).

From the api I query a boolean field `featured`. My generic PostList component:

```
const PostList = ({ posts }: Props) => {

  return (
    <div>
      {posts
        .filter(({ featured }) => {
          return featured;
        })
        .map(({ id, name, slug }) => (
          <PostTeaser key={id} title={name} url={slug} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostList;
```

The `PostTeaser.tsx` component:

```
const PostTeaser = ({ title, url }: Props) => {

  return (
    <Link to={url}>
      <div>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default PostTeaser;
```

I don't want to copy all code again and do something like `return !featured`. Is there a way to somehow combine this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether `posts` has at least one post that has `featured` equal to true by using `some`. If it does, filter out the posts to show only the featured posts. If it doesn't, show all the posts.

```
const PostList = ({ posts }: Props) => {

  const hasFeaturedPost = posts.some(post => post.featured);

  let updatedPosts;

  if (hasFeaturedPosts) {
    updatedPosts = posts.filter(post => post.featured);
  } else {
    updatedPosts = posts;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {updatedPosts
        .map(({ id, name, slug }) => (
          <PostTeaser key={id} title={name} url={slug} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostList;
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example of what a post would look like? Also, should `projects` be `posts` in the code snippet?

Comment: I think I get it now. See my updated answer and let me know if that makes sense